# Generate projectile motion by specifying coordinates

Tags: matlab, projectile

I want to plot one half, the positive increasing half, of a projectile motion passing through a specified coordinate on the y axis say till the apex of the midpoint or mean of the motion.For example, by specifying the coordinates starting from (0,0) to (1000,150) and only the positive half of the curve is plotted since the other half will be symmetric. The apex of the first half of the curve touches at (1000,150). Can somebody please post the code for that.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe if this is homework type problem you need to tag it as such. Also it is generally accepted you show some effort to solve your problem (post code in progress, or example) and understand that questions of type "Do my work for me" might be closed. Please read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/152388)

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a physics question. Have you read about [projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Parabolic_trajectory) and know how the `plot` command works in `MATLAB`?

Comment: This is both a programming and projectile motion issue and I do not know either of them.I could not find the homeowork tag,else I would have done the same.

Comment: @ja72 The homework tag is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're looking for a quadratic curve

```
h(t) = a + b t + c t^2
```

Such that it goes through the points `(0,0)` and `(x,y)`:

```
0 = a                 #  ->  a = 0
y = a + b x  + c x^2  #  ->  y = x (b + c x)
```

You also want the slope of the curve

```
h'(t) = b + 2 c t
```

to be zero at the apex `(x,y)`

```
0 = b + 2 c x         #  ->  b = -2 c x
```

Hence you have

```
y = x (-2 c x + c x)  #  ->  c = -y / x^2
```

So the code you want is

```
x = 1000;
y = 150;
a = 0;
c = -y/x^2;
b = -2*c*x;

t = 0:x;
h = a + b*t + c*t.^2;

plot(t,h)
grid
```

Which gives you this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. However, when I plotted with the exact code as yours, the Y axis in my case just went to 80 which is strange as in the program it is mentioned to be 150.So,no matter what I mention for Y axis,the graph does never plot till that y coordinate!What can be the problem?